# Android Jsoup html to string?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am new for Jsoup Html to String Parser.

i am using this html link [click](http://www.ndtv.com/article/india/pranab-mukherjee-resigns-as-finance-minister-pm-to-take-additional-charge-says-sources-236331)

i want to get image and storycontent and title.

if u know about Jsoup please ans here.

thanks.

Comment: take a look at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Comment: hi how can i get description alone??

Comment: JSoup's documentation is well written. You should read it, and come back here showing what you have already tried.

Comment: After connect with the URL and with a JSOUP document object generated in memory, you need to parse it. The HTML Div element with the id="storycontent" contains your text.

Comment: I'm trying like this but not working                                     Elements images = doc.select("div storycontent");  
System.out.println("imaString   "+images.toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for text

```
Element images = doc.select("div#storycontent");
```

and after that:

```
System.out.println("imaString "+images.text());
```

For images you need to find "img" tag in "doc" to get the URL.